# Is Hibernation mode warm booting or cold booting?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture, boot, processor

I have been reading  articles on booting, nowhere I found info about booting in Hibernation mode. Is it a warm booting or cold booting?

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-cold-booting-and-warm-booting/

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, there is [this answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-warm-booting-and-cold-booting-in-a-computer/answer/Sooraj-Vijaya):

> Hibernation process will store whatever data on RAM into hard drive
>   before the machine is turned off. Resuming from hibernation will
>   result computer in starting on cold boot, however it will load
>   whatever contents on the RAM just as before the computer hibernates.

As a side note, SO usually isn't the place to ask that kind of hardware questions, especially when no code is involved. Take a look at [SuperUser](https://www.superuser.com) instead. :)